# Cache memory: What is the difference between a tag and an index?

Tags: caching, cpu, cpu-architecture, memory-address

I read a lot of articles and watched videos explaining the concept of cache memory but I still can't get what the difference is between an index and a tag in the address format. They all say that we need an index because otherwise multiple locations would get hashed to the same location within the cache. But I don't understand. Can someone please explain?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

An address as a simple number, usually taken as an unsigned integer:

```
+---------------------------+
|          address          |
+---------------------------+
```

The same address — the same overall number — is decomposed by the cache into piece parts called fields:

```
+----------------------------+
|    tag    | index | offset |
+----------------------------+
```

For any given cache, the tag width, index width, and offset width are in bits and are fixed, and, for any given address, each field, of course, has a value we can determine given that we know the address and the widths of the fields for the given cache.

Caches store replication of main memory in chunks called blocks.  To find the block address of some address, keep its tag and index bits as is, but set the block offset bits to zeros.

---

Let's say there are two addresses: A and B.  A has a tag, index and offset, as does B have a tag, index, and offset.

We want to know if A and B match to the level of the block of memory — which means we care about tag & index bits matching, but not about offset bits.

You can see from the above that two addresses can be different yet have the same index — many addresses will share the same index yet have different tag or different offset bits.

Now, let's say that B is an address known to be cached.  That means that the block of memory for B's tag and B's index is in the cache.  The whole block is in the cache, which is all address with the same tag & index, and any possible offset bits.

Let's say that A is some address the program wants to access.  The cache's job is to determine if A and B refer to the same block of memory, if so then since B is in the cache, access of A is a hit in the cache, while if A and B don't refer to the same block of memory, then there is a miss in the cache.

Caches employ a notion of an array.  They use the index positions for the elements of the array, to simplify their operation.  A simple (direct mapped) cache will have a block stored at each index position in the array (other caches will have more than one block stored at each index position in the array: this refers to the cache's set associativity level, number of "ways", as in 2-way or 4-way, etc..).  To find a desired element, A, we need to look in the cache.  This is done by taking A's index position and using it as the index in the cache array.  If the element already there has a block for address B, and B's tag stored there is the same tag value as A's, then both index position and tags match — index matches because we looked in the right place, and tags match because the cache stores B's tag and we have all of A so can compare A's tag with B's tag.

Such a cache will never store the block for an address at an index position different than the index position value for its address.  So, there is only one index position to look at to see if the cache stores the block associated with an address, A.

---

> They all say that we need an index because otherwise multiple locations would get hashed to the same location within the cache

There is a degenerate case in cache architecture where the index size is 0 bits wide.  This means that regardless of the actual address, A, all addresses are stored at the same one index position.  Such as cache is "fully associative" and does not use the index field (or the index field has zero width).

The benefit of the index (when present in the cache architecture) is a simplification of the hardware: it has to only look at blocks stored at the index of A, and never at blocks stored at other indexes within the cache.

The benefit of not using an index is that one address will never evict another merely due to having the same index; fully associative caches are subject to less cache thrashing.